# Слайдер с отступом

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, owl-carousel

Помогите пожалуйста как сделать слайдер который имеет отступ с одной стороны, при прокрутке первого элемента слайдер уходит на ширину экрана? ( картинку прилагаю)
[image: Слайдер с отступом]

Comment: добавить слайдеру `padding-left`. после смены слайда, ивентом `afterChange` проверить какой слайд активен (метод `slickCurrentSlide`), если не 0, то убрать паддинг, а если 0 - добавить. в документации к слайдеру есть описания нужных функций

Comment: А если весь контент на сайте в контейнере, левая сторона слайдера тоже выравнена по левую сторону контейнера, неужели придется padding left подбирать на все расширения?

Comment: можно узнать расстояние от левого края экрана до слайдера `offset().left` и добавить слайдеру отрицательный `margin-left` и задать такой же `padding`